# Starting new transaction in Spring bean

Tags: java, spring, transactions

We have:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class MyClass implementes MyInterface { ...
```

MyInterface has a single method: `go()`.

When go() executes we start a new transaction which commits/rollbacks when the method is complete - this is fine.

Now let's say in go() we call a private method in MyClass that has `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW`.  It seems that Spring "ignores" the REQUIRES_NEW annotation and does not start a new transaction.  I believe this is because Spring AOP operates on the interface level (MyInterface) and does not intercept any calls to MyClass methods.  Is this correct?

Is there any way to start a new transaction within the go() transaction?  Is the only way to call *another* Spring managed bean that has transactions configured as REQUIRES_NEW?

---

**Update**: Adding that when clients execute `go()` they do so via a reference to the interface, not the class:

```
@Autowired
MyInterface impl;

impl.go();
```

Answer (score 93, accepted):

From the Spring reference 2.5:

> When using proxies, the `@Transactional` annotation should only be applied to 
>   methods with public visibility. If you do annotate protected, private or 
>   package-visible methods with the `@Transactional` annotation, no error will 
>   be raised, but the annotated method will not exhibit the configured transactional
>   settings.

So Spring ignores `@Transactional` annotation on non-public methods.

Also,

> In proxy mode (which is the default), only 'external' method calls coming in
>   through the proxy will be intercepted.  This means that 'self-invocation', 
>   i.e. a method within the target object calling some other method of the target 
>   object, won't lead to an actual transaction at runtime even if the invoked 
>   method is marked with `@Transactional`!

So even if you make your method `public`, calling it from within a method of same class will not start a new transaction.

You can use `aspectj` mode in transaction settings so that the transaction related code is weaved in the class and no proxy is created at runtime.

See [the reference document](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/reference/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations) for more details.

Another possible way of doing this is fetching the spring proxy of the class in the class itself and call methods on it rather than `this`:

```
@Service
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class SomeService {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    private SomeService  getSpringProxy() {
        return applicationContext.getBean(this.getClass());
    }

    private void doSomeAndThenMore() {
        // instead of
        // this.doSometingPublicly();
        // do the following to run in transaction
        getSpringProxy().doSometingPublicly();
    }

    public void doSometingPublicly() {
        //do some transactional stuff here
    }

}
```

Answer (score 58):

`@Transactional` will only be noticed if it's on a `public` method, due to the way Spring AOP works.

However, you can [programmatically start a new transaction](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-programmatic) if you desire, using `TransactionTemplate`, e.g.

```
TransactionTemplate txTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(txManager);                
txTemplate.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW);
txTemplate.execute(status -> {
        // do stuff
});
```

Comment: But even if `@Transactional` is on a public method of MyClass, it still appears that Spring won't pick it up **unless** the method is defined in the interface - correct?

Comment: To add, this is because the client that is executing the go() method in question has a reference to the interface, not the class.

Comment: @Marcus: Sort of. If `MyClass` implements an interface, then Spring will use only that interface for generating the transactional proxy, and ignore even public, non-interface methods. However, if `MyClass` implements no interface, then all public methods will be used.

Comment: It's not important if it's an interface, it just needs to be behind a proxxy,  an injected `@Autowired` dependency.

Answer (score 11):

In short you have to call the method though proxy to achieve the transactional behaviour. 
It is possible to call a "REQUIRES_NEW" in the same bean, as asked in the question. To do that you have to make a "self" reference.
In spring its is not straightforward possible. You have to inject it 
with @Resource annotation.

```
@Service("someService")
public class ServieImpl implements Service {

   @Resource(name = "someService")
   Service selfReference;

   @Transactional
   public void firstMethod() {
       selfReference.secondMethod();
   }

   @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) 
   public void secondMethod() {    
         //do in new transaction
   }

}
```

The invocation in firstMethod calls the proxy and not "this" which should make the "REQUIRES_NEW" transaction to work.