# Spring - @Cacheable annotation not working on java method

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching

When adding @Cacheable annotation on a method performing a simple Java code, on application execution, breakpoint inside the method is triggered. Does this mean that the result was not cached?

Configuration used:

```
spring.cache.type=redis
spring.redis.host=localhost
spring.redis.port=[port]
spring.cache.redis.time-to-live=[some value]
```

Note that the @Cacheable is working fine in the same project when put before a database method

Comment: You are expecting an answer without adding code/configuration? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, especially the [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) part and improve your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it work, we need to call the method annotated with @Cacheable from a different Java class. Otherwise it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this means that the result was not cached.

> In this case, if any of the caches contains the required result, the result is returned and the method is not invoked.

[Source](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-cache-tutorial#)

In order to make use of a cache, the method must be invoked with the same parameters again. However, there are limitations, as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16899739/11210504) points out.

Comment: I was able to make it work by moving all code related to cached method and its sub methods to a new service class, however, my new problem is that the cache is alwatys called and never refreshed. How should I fix this? in other words, the methods code is never called. Configuration for cache time to live is: spring.cache.redis.time-to-live=60000

Comment: Not sure what happened, but I fixed the issue by running this command in redis to clear cache: redis-cli FLUSHALL