# Why is caching not working on wrapped reactive Methods

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-cache

I am trying to use the spring-cache abstraction. In my case I want to cache a method call that produces a Mono.

My pom contains two dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

With this dependencies (Spring boot parent 2.6.3) I have two very simple Services:

```
@Component
public class TestService1 {

    @Cacheable("testRequests1")
    public Mono<String> testMethodWrapper(String input) {
        return testMethod(input).cache();
    }

    public Mono<String> testMethod(String input) {
        System.out.println("uncached call on service1");
        return Mono.just("test1 " + input);
    }
}
```

and

```
@Component
public class TestService2 {


    public Mono<String> testMethodWrapper(String input) {
        return testMethod(input);
    }

    @Cacheable("testRequests2")
    public Mono<String> testMethod(String input) {
        System.out.println("uncached call on service2");
        return Mono.just("test2 " + input).cache();
    }
}
```

The difference is, that the in `TestService1` the wrapper method is cached and in `TestService2` the inner method.
When I run my Spring Application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
        TestService1 testService1 = ctx.getBean(TestService1.class);
        TestService2 testService2 = ctx.getBean(TestService2.class);
        testService1.testMethodWrapper("test").block();
        testService1.testMethodWrapper("test").block();
        testService2.testMethodWrapper("test").block();
        testService2.testMethodWrapper("test").block();
    }
}
```

I get

```
2022-02-18 13:40:47.330  INFO 20240 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 1.8 seconds (JVM running for 2.793)
uncached call on service1
uncached call on service2
uncached call on service2
```

Why are calls to the method `testMethod` in the `TestService2` not cached? What part from the `Mono.cache()` [documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html):

> Turn this Mono into a hot source and cache last emitted signals for further Subscriber.

did I not understand and how can I cache calls to `testMethod` in `TestService2` that represents the scenario I need to implement?

Comment: In general, Spring advice doesn't apply to _self-calls_ because they don't travel through the Spring proxy. This is more commonly seen with `@Transactional` but also applies to `@Cacheable`.

Comment: thx, I did totally look at the wrong direction here. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16899604/