# Spring cache proxy issue when method called within the same class

Tags: java, caching, spring-aop, aspect

Here is the interface code. Here the abstract method `getItemById` is called inside `findById`. This was causing the spring proxy to not work as intented.

```
  @Nullable
  T getItemById(@NotNull final String id);

  @NotNull
  default Optional<T> findById(@Nullable final String id) {
    return isBlank(id) ? Optional.empty() : Optional.ofNullable(getItemById(id));
  }
```

The following is an implementation of of the interface :

```
      @Override
      @Nullable
      @Cacheable(value = "cartCache")
      public Cart getItemById(@NotNull final String id) {
        //get data from DB
      }
```

When I call the method from the autowired class directly `service.getItemById()` then it would work. But when I call `service.findById()`it isn't working due to aspect not getting applied for the method.I have read tht aspectj being a solution but I don't know it's working very well and how to implement it in the following case.

I have came across a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16899604/spring-cache-cacheable-not-working-while-calling-from-another-method-of-the-s/34091265#34091265) which uses `@Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)` annotation. But it is on a class and an object of the service is also create inside itself. As I coulnd't do this in my interface, I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Where is your full, minimal, reproducible example? I cannot compile and debug an incoherent set of snippets. There are simply too many options what you could have done wrong, and this is not a guessing game.

Comment: Looking at this question again, I guess it is simply a duplicate of [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56616248/1082681).