# Springboot Caching is not working as expected

Tags: spring-boot, caching

I am trying to implement caching via SpringBoot but its still always submitting the message.

I have implemented my CacheManager

```
@Component
@EnableCaching
public class SimpleCacheCustomizer implements CacheManagerCustomizer<ConcurrentMapCacheManager> {

    @Override
    public void customize(ConcurrentMapCacheManager cacheManager) {
        cacheManager.setCacheNames(Arrays.asList("bcaType"));
        cacheManager.setStoreByValue(true);
        cacheManager.setAllowNullValues(false);
    }
}
```

and then Have one of the class

```
@SpringComponent
@CacheConfig(cacheNames = {
        "bcaType" })
public class MsgBcaTypeCategory {
```

in which added @Cacheble on one method

`@Cacheable("bcaType")
    private String postMessageToGateway(String url) throws MalformedURLException {
        SrpInvokerImpl srpInvokerImpl = new SrpInvokerImpl();
        MsgGetBcaTypeCriteriaNewMsgBuilder msgGetBcaTypeCriteriaNewMsgBuilder = new MsgGetBcaTypeCriteriaNewMsgBuilder();

        return srpInvokerImpl.postMessageToGateway(msgGetBcaTypeCriteriaNewMsgBuilder.prepareMessage(),
                new URL(url));

    }`


My expectation is whenever same URL is coming as param then it should return from cache but right now everytime its calling 
srpInvokerImpl.postMessageToGateway.

Can anyone guide me what I am doing wrong here ?
I tried following the steps mentioned in the URL
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cache-tutorial

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Cache @Cacheable - not working while calling from another method of the same bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16899604/spring-cache-cacheable-not-working-while-calling-from-another-method-of-the-s)

Comment: Everywhere I find example using bean Dao, Repository etc. But for me the method to be cached has one String param and returns a String. 
Not sure whether this is happening due to the below mentioned reason or something else
_There is a proxy class generated that intercepts all requests and responds with the cached value, but 'internal' calls within the same class will not get the cached value._

Comment: Annotations only can work (usually) when the regarding methods are called from another class (from outside), since the proxy would not be able to catch them if not.

Comment: I tried moving the method to be cached in seperate class
 
`@SpringComponent
@CacheConfig(cacheNames = {
        "bcaType" })
public class CacheData {

    @Cacheable
    public String postMessageToGateway(String url) throws MalformedURLException {
        SrpInvokerImpl srpInvokerImpl = new SrpInvokerImpl();
        MsgGetBcaTypeCriteriaNewMsgBuilder msgGetBcaTypeCriteriaNewMsgBuilder = new MsgGetBcaTypeCriteriaNewMsgBuilder();

        return srpInvokerImpl.postMessageToGateway(msgGetBcaTypeCriteriaNewMsgBuilder.prepareMessage(), new URL(url));

    }
}`
still same !!!