# Configure a simple cache on a springboot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching

I have a spring boot application where I am trying to implement a simple cache without any external providers(redis, etc.).

I just want to cache the response from the function `getFromDatabase` but each time I run that function, the print line still gets executed which point me to the fact that caching is not working.

However, if I put the `@Cacheable` annotation on the `@PostMapping` itself, then cache works.
Am I implementing this wrong?

My main class has the following

```java
    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
    import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;

    @SpringBootApplication
    @EnableCaching
    public class YourApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(YourApplication.class, args);
        }
    }
```

And my controller has the following

```java
    import org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

    @RestController
    public class Controller {

        @PostMapping("/temp")
        public String retrieve() {
            return getFromDatabase("yes");
        }

        @Cacheable(value = "databaseCache", key = "#key")
        public String getFromDatabase(String key) {
            System.out.println("Retrieving from database");
            return "Fake";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring doesn't create proxies for all methods in a class. It considers methods only with specific annotations. That is why `@Cacheable` annotation works with `@PostMapping` and is ignored in the example you provided.

I would advise you to move your `getFromDatabase` method into a separate `@Service` class to solve this issue.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
public class YourApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(YourApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Contoller

```java
@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController
public class Controller {

    @Autowired
    Service service;

    @PostMapping("/temp")
    public String retrieve() {
        return service.getFromDatabase("yes");
    }
}
```

Service

```java
@org.springframework.stereotype.Service
public class Service {

    @Cacheable(value = "databaseCache", key = "#key")
    public String getFromDatabase(String key) {
        System.out.println("Retrieving from database");
        return "Fake";
    }
}
```

Comment: There is also a good explanation of why the example provided in the original question doesn't work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16899604/spring-cache-cacheable-not-working-while-calling-from-another-method-of-the-s