# Can't execute sql statement after catching error

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, spring-boot, jdbc

I catch the exception (I specially do mistake in SQL statement to get SQLException) when import records to database and I want in this catch update record in another table (in normal situation when we don't have an exception I also run this statement after importing records). But the problem is that record in another table not updated, however, in [console](https://i.ibb.co/bmLnC0W/ee.png) I see that this updating successfull.

Firtsly, whem user import from FE records, in BE we get this POST-request in controller (`It_tableController`), after that call sevice (`It_tableService`) and service call DAO (`It_tableDAO`). And in DAO method I catch the SQLException (in `It_tableDAO`) and try to update record in another table (using `import_sessionsDAO`), but it doesn't works.

So why sql statement executes but not updates the record in catch block?

it_tableController.java:

```java
    @RequestMapping(value = "/*URL*/", 
                    method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')")
    public ResponseEntity<List<EntityResponse>> addData(@PathVariable Integer originator_id,
                                                        @PathVariable Integer deployment_type_id,
                                                        @PathVariable Integer template_id,  
                                                        @PathVariable String filename,
                                                        @RequestBody String[][] data,
                                                        @CurrentUser UserPrincipal currentUser) {
        logger.info("Performing /*URL*/ POST request");                                                             
        List<EntityResponse> response = it_tableService.addData(
                deployment_type_id, 
                template_id, 
                originator_id, 
                filename, 
                currentUser.getId(),
                currentUser.getUsername(), 
                data);
        return new ResponseEntity<List<EntityResponse>>(response, HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);

    }
```

It_tableService.java:

```java
     public List<EntityResponse> addData (
             Integer deployment_type_id, 
             Integer template_id, 
             Integer originator_id, 
             String filename,
             Long user_id,
             String username,
             String[][] data) {
        if (!import_sessionsDAO.retrieveActiveImport_sessions(deployment_type_id).isEmpty()) 
            { return null; } 
        else {
            Timestamp timestamp = import_sessionsDAO.insertImport_session(username, deployment_type_id, true, filename);
            List<EntityResponse> responseItTable = new ArrayList<EntityResponse>();
                responseItTable = 
                    it_tableDAO.addData(deployment_type_id, template_id, originator_id, filename, user_id, username, data);
            import_sessionsDAO.updateStatusOfImport_session(false, username, deployment_type_id, filename);
                return responseItTable;
        }
     }

     public Integer retrieveLastIdInTable(Integer deployment_type_id) {
        Integer responseLastId = it_tableDAO.retrieveLastIdInTable(deployment_type_id);
        return responseLastId;
    }
```

it_tableDAO.java:

```java
    @Transactional
    public List<EntityResponse> addData(Integer deployment_type_id, 
                                        Integer template_id, 
                                        Integer originator_id, 
                                        String filename, 
                                        Long user_id,
                                        String username,
                                        String[][] data) {

        List<ColumnsNameModel> columnsName = getColumnsNameForDeploymentType(template_id);
        List<EntityResponse> newRows       = new ArrayList<EntityResponse>();
        String tableName                   = getTableNameForDeploymentType(deployment_type_id);     
        String primaryKeyItTable           = getPrimaryKeyItTableQuery(tableName);      
        // int columnsCountToItTable           = getColumnsNameToItTable(columnsName, data);

        for (int i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
            String INSERT_IT_TABLE_QUERY_part2 = "";
            String updateFieldsOnConflict = "";
            INSERT_IT_TABLE_QUERY = "INSERT INTO kddb." + tableName + " (";  

            for (int j = 0; j < data[0].length; j++) {
                String column = "";
                for (ColumnsNameModel columnName: columnsName) {
                    if (Objects.equals(columnName.getSource_field_name(), data[0][j]) ) {
                        column = columnName.getField_name_it_table();
                        if (j == 0 ) { 
                            INSERT_IT_TABLE_QUERY += column; 
                            updateFieldsOnConflict += column + "=EXCLUDED." + column;
                        }
                        else { 
                            INSERT_IT_TABLE_QUERY += ", " + column; 
                            updateFieldsOnConflict += ", " + column + "=EXCLUDED." + column;
                        }  
                        INSERT_IT_TABLE_QUERY_part2 += ConcatinateToQuery(data[i][j], j);
                    }
                }
            }
            updateFieldsOnConflict += ", import_user_id=EXCLUDED.import_user_id"+
                    ", import_date=EXCLUDED.import_date"+
                    ", import_file=EXCLUDED.import_file";
            INSERT_IT_TABLE_QUERY += ", import_user_id, import_date, import_file)\n VALUES (";

            INSERT_IT_TABLE_QUERY += INSERT_IT_TABLE_QUERY_part2;
            INSERT_IT_TABLE_QUERY += ", " + user_id + ", \'" + new java.sql.Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime()) + "\', \'"
                    + filename + "\'";

            String uniqueKey = getUniqueKeyItTableQuery(tableName);
            if (!Objects.equals(uniqueKey, null)) {
                INSERT_IT_TABLE_QUERY += ") \n ON CONFLICT (" + uniqueKey + ") DO UPDATE SET \n" + updateFieldsOnConflict; 
            }
            else {
                INSERT_IT_TABLE_QUERY += ") \n ON CONFLICT (" + primaryKeyItTable + ") DO UPDATE SET \n" + updateFieldsOnConflict; 
            }
            GeneratedKeyHolder holder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
            try {
            jdbcTemplate.update(new PreparedStatementCreator() {
                @Override
                public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection con) throws SQLException {
                    PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(INSERT_IT_TABLE_QUERY, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
                    return statement;
                }
            }, holder);

            GeneratedKeyHolder holder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
            try {
            jdbcTemplate.update(new PreparedStatementCreator() {
                @Override
                public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection con) throws SQLException {
                    PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(INSERT_IT_TABLE_QUERY, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
                    return statement;
                }
            }, holder);
            } catch (Exception e) {
/* ============ THIS STATEMENT NOT UPDATE THE TABLE */
                import_sessionsDAO.updateStatusOfImport_session(false, username, deployment_type_id, filename); 
                logger.info("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
            }

            /* some another actions */

        return newRows;
    }
```

import_sessionsDAO.java:

```java
    private static String UPDATE_STATUS_OF_IMPORT_SESSION  = 
        "\n UPDATE kddb.import_sessions SET running_status = ? \n" + 
        " WHERE username = ? AND deployment_type_id = ? AND \n" +
        "       filename = ?; ";    

    public void updateStatusOfImport_session(Boolean running_status, String username, Integer deployment_type_id, String filename) {
        logger.info(UPDATE_STATUS_OF_IMPORT_SESSION);
        jdbcTemplate.update(UPDATE_STATUS_OF_IMPORT_SESSION,
            running_status, 
            username, 
            deployment_type_id, 
            filename);
        logger.info("Successfully update a status (set {}) of record with parameters: username={} deployment_type_id={} filename={}", 
            running_status,
            username,
            deployment_type_id,
            filename);
    }
```

Comment: In PostgreSQL, a database error causes a transaction abort. You cannot execute other statements in that transaction. BTW: It would greatly improve your question if you reduce your code to a [mre] and post the original exception, and the subsequent exception you get.

Comment: @mark-rotteveel so is it possible to create a new transaction in try-catch block?

Comment: AFAIK, not when you're using `@Transactional`. However, your problem seems to be one where you should be using `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE` instead.

Comment: @mark-rotteveel yes, I use `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE` but the problem was that when I call `import_sessionsDAO.updateStatusOfImport_session()` I want update record in another table

Comment: @mark-rotteveel thanks for help! I think in this case I need to make something like new HTTP-request from frontend and update this table by this way.

Comment: Sorry, I has missed that in the code. Which is why it is a good idea to use a [mre] instead of your actual code: it reduces the scope and focusses on the actual problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Starting new transaction in Spring bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037006/starting-new-transaction-in-spring-bean)